# set theory, infinite set proof, is it alright?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

$\Bbb{N}$ is the natural numbers set (included $0$).

let be $n\in\Bbb{N}$, $A_n = \{x\in \Bbb{N}|0\leq x \leq n\}$

prove of disprove:

$$\forall n,k \in \Bbb{N},\exists m \in\Bbb{N}(|A_m - A_n|=k)$$

In my proof I'm relying on a previous proof that $|A_{n+1}-A_n|=1$.

[image]

is it ok or weird to assign k to the index? thanks.

Comment: Yeah in second though im moving k out of the index, not that it's wrong right now, but makes more sense (|An-An|=0 -> |(An+K)-An|=0+K-> m=n+k

Comment: What do you mean by $\;A_n-A_m\;$ ? Set difference? Because if you do then the claim is trivial as all the sets involved are finite...

Comment: of course the sets involved are finite, but this proof should prove that even if you take an infinite set An, |An+1-An|=1, and there exist m$\in$N such that Am-An=K (if m=n+k, it exist).

Comment: by |Am-An| I'm talking about the number of members in the difference, | | is a symbol for number of elements, |{1,2,3}|=3

Comment: I can't see why "this proof" should prove what you say, @Seth. The proof is about the given sets in the given problem, and **all** those sets are finite and thus their difference is *always* finite: either zero or a natural number.

Comment: but N is infinite, so in theory An could be infinite, but we know that |An+1-An|=1 (An+1 is the set that have 1 more element than An), so this proof works even for an infinite number!, I'm still not saying you are wrong... I could be wrong, I don't know, It's always hard for me when it comes to infinity.

Comment: No, not in theory not in nothing: by **your definition**, each set $\;A_n\;$ is finite. Period. That $\;\Bbb N\;$ is infinite has no bearing in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\;n,k\in\Bbb N\;$ , take

$$A_{n+k}\setminus A_n:=\left\{x\in\Bbb N\;;\;x\in A_{n+k}\;\wedge\;x\notin A_n\right\}=\left\{x\in\Bbb N\;;\;n<x\le n+k\right\}\implies$$

$$\implies\left|A_{n+k}\setminus A_n\right|=n+k-n=k$$

Comment: thank you, can I say now that there exist m$\in$N such that m=n+k->|Am-An|=k ?

Comment: Well, if you insist in calling $\;m\;$ to $\;n+k\;$, yes.